# Silverlight deep zoom without asp.net?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, deepzoom

I want to use deep zoom in Silverlight, but it seems that the images don't get sharp when I'm using my Silverlight application in a standalone html file, and not through iis. I'm able to zoom in and out, but the images is blurred. This works fine if I'm using a asp.net web site. Is it at all possible to use Silverlight deep zoom without iis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Deep zoom creates a test htm in the ClientBin folder of the Web project it creates when you export.  I can open my copy of this HTM directly from the file system and all the multi scale functions continue to work fine.

Comment: Are you sure this works for you? When I try this I am able to zoom in and out and pan the image, but it stays blurred.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I can't understand why it wouldn't work, all the URLs are relative to the ClientBin folder, it shouldn't matter whether the protocol is file:/// or http://

Comment: I agree it should work, but I have tried for quite a while now, and the results are the same. So frustrating!

Comment: Can you provide more details?  For example how many images have you stiched together, what resolution are the source images?

Comment: I'm trying to just make a test at first, so I used Deep Zoom Composer and added only 3 images. They are 3504x2336, 3504x2336 and 2272x1704. You can see one of my test her: http://josteinskaar.com/tests/silverlight/silverzoom1a/test.html. THis is the Tag Browser template. I tried with other exports as well.

Comment: I found the problem. Kirupa.com tipped me to use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/, and then I found my problem: A lot of "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" messages. I carelessly had used norwegian characters in my image names.